# Function to get a list element - C

Tags: c, list

My list structure

```
struct Path{
    int h; //horisental 
    int v; //vertical
    Path_t * next;
};
```

its a circular list, which means that the last element of the list's `Path_t * next` points on the first element of the list,

int h values are (0)NOTHING,(1)RIGHT or (-1)LEFT

int v values are (0)NOTHING,(1)UP or (-1)DOWN

so i'm going to use that directions to move a shape

NOW HERE IS THE PROBLEM :

i need to write a function that gets me one element of the list and based on that i will move the shape, and the next time i call it i will get the next element of the list and not the one i already checked

Answer (score 0):

You can define a global variable to implement that. For example:

```
Path_t *currPath = NULL;
```

And let's say the described function named "getNextPath":

```
Path_t *getNextPath()
{
    Path_t *pathToReturn = NULL;

    if ( currPath == NULL )
    {
        currPath = headOfYourList;
        pathToReturn = currPath;
    }
    else
    {
        pathToReturn = currPath->next;
        currPath = pathToReturn;
    }

    return pathToReturn;    
}
```

Initially, "currPath" will be NULL and with the first call of "getNextPath" the head of your list will be returned. Otherwise, the "next" of the previous path (previous path is the path that has been returned in the last call of "getNextPath") will be returned and stored for the next call of the function (to get the "next" of it).

Answer (score 0):

i can't really use a global variables in my case, so I've done something like

```
 typedef struct {
        int type;
        clock_t appear;
        int x;
        int y;
        int health;
        float freq;
        Path_t dir; //for the current Path
        Shot_t * shot;
        char ** shape;
        Path_t * path;
    }Invader_t;
```

and right when i finish filling my `Path_t` list i give the `Path_t dir` the head of the list and every time i move my invader i change the value of `Path_t * dir` and it works fine.